# How to Wait until page is fully loaded with Intern js

Tags: selenium, javascript, uiautomation

I was trying to automate the UI testing of an application with `Intern js`.

But I am having a problem finding the way to wait until the page is fully loaded. After researching for a while, I found that `pollUntil` might be the solution I'm looking for but that too doesn't seem to work (maybe my implementation is wrong).

Currently *my code doesn't wait at all*. Can someone please help me with this?

**My Code:**

```
 define([
  'intern!object',
  'intern/chai!assert',
  'Automation/ConfigFiles/dataurl',
  'Automation/pages/login/loginpage',
  'intern/dojo/node!fs',
  'intern/dojo/node!leadfoot/helpers/pollUntil'
   ], function (registerSuite, assert,dataurl, LoginPage,fs,pollUntil) {
     registerSuite(function () {
      var loginPage;
      var values;
      return {
         setup: function () {
            var data = fs.readFileSync(loginpage, 'utf8');
            json=JSON.parse(data);
            console.log('###########Setting Up Login Page Test##########')
            this.remote
             .get(require.toUrl(json.locator.URL))
           .then(pollUntil(this.remote.findById('uname').isDisplayed(),6000)// here i want  to wait until page is loaded
.waitForDeletedByClassName('loading').end().sleep(600000)// here i want to wait until loading component is disappered
    values = json.values;
    loginPage = new LoginPage(this.remote,json.locator);
   },
'successful login': function () {
    console.log('##############Login Success Test############')
    return loginPage
        .login(values.unamevalue,values.pwdvalue)
      },

// …additional tests…
     };
   });
  });
```

Comment: Instead, can you find more elements on the page (elements that might give you some indication the page has fully loaded) and waits until they load?